# Segue with code

Tags: swift, segue

I have a uisearch bar with code to search some data. After I click on some of that, I need to push to another UIView.

So I am using this

```
let vc=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "id") as! mapViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It works well, but after segue, the view is not in the narvigation controller, because it is a present. So I wish to use show segue.
Then I change the code to

```
    self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

When I run it, it does not work and shows

```
"while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated."
```

What should I do to use show segue here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pushViewController` method

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message implies (well, it shouts that right in your face).
You should not start the (animated) segue of yours until the
last animated nav action will have finished.
The code (of yours) needs restructuring to allow for that to happen.

Comment: Sorry i m not sure what that means

Answer (score 0):

Your current ViewController also need to be in navigation Stack after that you can push another controller . First set current ViewController as rootViewController of an Navigation Controller and then push your mapViewController from your current Controller.